# How to update an ASP.Net View without user interaction (using WebHooks)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, webhooks

I created a simple ASP.Net application to display some information on a page. I want to update the page from the server without having to refresh the page.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var item = "Foo";
        var amount = GetAmount(item);
        var model = new SampleModel { Item = item, Amount = amount };
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Sample.Models.SampleModel

<div>
   <p class="item">@Model.Item</p>
   @if (Model.Amount == 0)
   {
       <p class="amount">FREE</p>
   }
   else
   {
       <p class="amount">@Model.Amount</p>
   }
</div>
```

---

My goal is to:

1. Create an API that exposes a WebHook.
2. Consume that WebHook from this ASP.Net MVC Application.
3. Update the current users view with the new amount.

Really not sure if this is possible, or how to do it?

Comment: did u create an API?

Comment: Well, you can put a javascript trying to get new data from server from times in times or use websocket/signalR. Take a look at: https://pusher.com/websockets and https://www.asp.net/signalr . Regards.